# redis:- session key not updating

Tags: session, express, redis

```
redisClient.set('sessionKey', userSession, function(err){
 console.log(err || 'sessionKey updated');
});
```

The above works.

But following does not update the existing session key.

```
redisClient.get(sessionKey, function(err, userSession){ // works fine
    userSession = // some modification;
    redisClient.set(sessionKey, userSession, function(err){
      console.log(err || 'sessionKey updated');
    });
 });
```

I'm using localhost with redistogo thru heroku. There is no error. Even the `console.log(err || 'sessionkey update');` prints

Comment: Nothing happens or do you get unexpected results?
Make sure the variables contain data

Comment: Express updates its session automatically before response is sent to the client. Probably, it simply overwrites all your changes with `req.session`.

Comment: actually the 'sessionKey update' prints on console. So the update should happen. But it does not. No error nothing.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny on localhost it works. not working on heroku.

Comment: Are you sure that no error occurs? Try logging with `console.log(err || 'sessionKey updated')`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny i'm using localhost with cloud redis service. yes i'm positive there is no error.

Comment: Does `redisClient.get(sessionKey, ...)` actually return something?

Comment: @robertklep made some changes in the question to illustrate.

Comment: Is `userSession` a complex object that you first need to run through `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: Yes, Json.parse then Json.stringify both included.

Comment: I think the problem is express is not permitting to change session data. Can I ask it to give permission?